# Favourite questions and answers from the 1st quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

First quarter has come to end. So, we are back with favorite questions and answers from the past quarter.

Following the tradition, we would ask the community to link your **favorite questions and answers created from 1<sup>st</sup>  January to 31<sup>st</sup>  March**.

You can search all eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2019-01..2019-03) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswers+created%3A2019-01..2019-03) posted in the past quarter. We received 550 questions and ~1.5k answers, here are some data queries.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the first quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/01/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the first quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/01/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the first quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/01/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answered you enjoyed. Since **this is not a competition**, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 9):

I was very glad when someone finally [**answered this old question about *Taxi Driver***](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/96786/49). From the comments it seemed like I wasn't the only one who had *kind* of a clue what an interesting answer to this question might look like. But other than just favouriting the question for "later" I didn't bother to delve deeper into this.

So I was really happy when Anne Daunted put up her answer detailing what this scene tells us about the film and the character and zeitgeist whose study the film utlimately is. Also another testament to answers usually being better than comments for, well, answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

I really enjoyed this question and the answer's historical relevance [Why are the books in the Game of Thrones citadel library shelved spine inwards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97347/why-are-the-books-in-the-game-of-thrones-citadel-library-shelved-spine-inwards/97351#97351)

Answer (score 3):

All these questions and answers are my favorite ones.

1. [BrettFromLA](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/8017/)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/96406/27264) to [**How do they film movies that take place in a single season?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96400/27264) asked by [Ver Nick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/11216/). Both question and answer are my favorite.
2. [iandotkelly](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/40/)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/97344/27264) to [**How does Leonard in “Memento” remember reading and writing?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97342/27264) asked by [umer arif](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/70631/). Both question and answer are my favorite.